# cannot ping home network, but can connect via remote desktop and access network's websites

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn

I am trying to reach my home network's VPN (hosted on my windows computer), I had everything port forwarded correctly and could reach it before but now i get an error "a connection to remove server could not be established". I cant seem to ping the network, however I can access my computer via Remote Desktop, and can access a local website that is port forwarded.

My current thoughts are that, either there is a firewall restriction on my network (university network), there is a problem with my computers configuration. Or there is a problem with my networks configuration.

I am led to believe its not a firewall issue because I tested from my phones Hotspot and i still had the same issue. I have also tried updating my computer, restarting, troubleshooting network adapters etc.

UPDATES:
I downloaded a network utility app for my phone and attempted to ping the server with no luck, however I can still access the website and RD from my phone.

To clarify,
incoming connections go through no-ip's dns lookup (i cant access from either dns or ip). the connection im trying to make would then go through the router (GT-AC5300). I then have a windows pc with a static ip that the router forwards ports for a couple of websites, game servers, micrsoft remote desktop, and a [native windows VPN tunnel](https://www.howtogeek.com/135996/how-to-create-a-vpn-server-on-your-windows-computer-without-installing-any-software/). I can access the websites and the rd server via my-dns.net:[port] however i cant reach the vpn server i set up, nor can i ping the server `ping my-dns.net` or `ping my-ip` on either my laptop or from my phones cellular connection

I'm not all that familiar with VPN servers, but windows allows me to automatically assign incoming devices an ip via DHCP. The server is fairly basic and theres no UI to tell me anything (or i dont know where to look)

I'm more concerned with the fact that I cannot ping the network, otherwise I would be more focused on the VPN configuration

Comment: You should be very clear about your configuration. What are the different nodes of the network involved ? Which softwares ? What does work ? (Is the VPN software tells everything is ok?) are their some pings that work ? Note that setting a VPN for accessing a whole network needs some route table tweaking (or some masquerading if some adresses can’t be published). Which route publishing have you done ?

Comment: I added some clarification ... Do you think I should add anything else

Comment: Network devices (for example firewalls) are commonly configured not ton respond to ping as a security measure.